# Div disappears when set to position fixed

Tags: css, css-position

I have a div with an id of `sidemenu1`, when `position` is anything but `fixed` it is visible, when I change it to `fixed` it becomes hidden and I cant find it.

```
#sidemenu1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 100vh;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 30;
  animation-name: sidemenuanimation;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}
```

It is just in the body, there is no container. I want it to follow on the side fixed, while I scroll through the rest of the doc.

Comment: I think Pangloss is right. Why you need to use top: 100vh?

Comment: i took that off entirely but it still wont show up, its the top of z-indexs should it not show up?

Comment: i put it inside a container:

Comment: #fixedbox{
    height: 300px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: forestgreen;
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 400;
    
   
}

Comment: and changed the position of the menu to absolute

Answer (score 0):

If you could provide the sample **html** and **css** maybe i will be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want, Ryan?

```css
#sidemenu1 {
           height: 15px;
           width: 150px;
           left: 10px;  
           background-color: aliceblue;
           float: left;
           position: fixed;
           z-index: 30;
           animation-name: sidemenuanimation;
           animation-play-state: paused;
           animation-fill-mode: forwards;
           animation-duration: 4s;
        }

        #fixedbox{ 
           height: 200px;
           width: 150px;
           background-color: forestgreen;
           float: left;
           position: fixed;
           z-index: 400;
           overflow:auto
        }
```

```html
    <div id="fixedbox">  
    <div id="sidemenu1">dsfasgsagsagasdg</div>    
       sadasdsa</br>
       sadasdsa</br>
       sadasdsa</br>
       sadasdsa</br>
       sadasdsa</br>
       sadasdsa</br>
       sadasdsa</br>
       sadasdsa</br>
       sadasdsa</br>
       sadasdsa</br>
       sadasdsa</br>
       sadasdsa</br>
       sadasdsa</br>
       sadasdsa</br>
       sadasdsa</br>
       sadasdsa</br>
       sadasdsa</br>
       sadasdsa</br>
    </div>
```